# How can I display a Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Report in an iPad App?

Tags: objective-c, sharepoint, ios4, reporting-services, ipad

This is more of a general "how do I get started" question. I would like to display my company's SSRS Integrated Sharepoint Reports in an iPad App, but I'm not sure where to start. Googling this concept didn't return any results.

We would like a native feel without displaying the reports in a Web View container.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the webservice to get the [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsmanagementservice2005.reportingservice2005.getreportparameters%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and build a little query interface.  You'd have to figure out what to put in your dropdown boxes I believe.

Get params with that and then submit call the [render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsexecutionservice2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) method which would return the report to you in the desired format.  Be sure to read the remarks there.

I have no clue if this would actually work.  My organization built an interface like this for reporting services 2000, but it used the [URL-based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153640%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) submitting method.

Good luck, I'd love to know if this works for you.

Comment: Absolutely great!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Most likely, I think I am going to build a Web Service on top of the Reporting Web Service and then just send back the report and render it in a Web View. As the project progresses I will update this post to let you know what I ended up doing etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using the web service is definitely your best bet.  You should be able to query all the parameter information you need from the service and then render it in various formats (html is probably your best bet).

I know it's definitely doable, as I've used the web service to build custom scripts that render and and send out PDF versions of reports.  It would essentially be the same task.  You can find plenty of information on the web for working with it.

Answer (score 2):

look at http://reports4you.software4you.com

The Website shows a server based solution to display reporting services reports on the ipad (including autentification, etc.)

Yours
Dirk

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2012 SPI, you can now access a SSRS report from an iPad by browsing the SharePoint library or viewing the report in a Web part.

For more information about viewing and interacting with SSRS reports on the iPad, see [View Reporting Services Reports on Apple iOS devices (SSRS iPad).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj659023.aspx)