# Display a SSRS reports in an iPad App

Tags: ipad, reporting-services, report

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display a Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Report in an iPad App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888885/how-can-i-display-a-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services-report-in-an-ipad-ap)
>   [render ssrs reports on ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737474/render-ssrs-reports-on-ipad)

How can I display a Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Report in an iPad App?